# HTML ¿Cómo puedo crear un botón que copie texto al portapapeles, pero que el texto no se vea en la página?

Tags: javascript, html, botón

hace rato estaba intentando crear un botón en HTML que al darle clic copie al portapapeles un texto o una URL, pero que estos mismos no se vean en la página. Ya he visto varias maneras pero en todas copia un texto que está se vea en la página, tipo así:
[image: idk]

Entonces lo que busco es que copie al portapapeles el texto o URL, sin que se vea este mismo texto en la página.. Ya he probado con ponerle "style="visibility: hidden;" y no me lo copia. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, en cómo puedo solucionarlo se lo agradecería mucho :D Por cierto soy nuevo en esto de programación =)
El código que estoy usando(no es mío) es el siguiente:

```
<button id="BotonCopiar" class="btn btn-primary">Copiar URL</button>
<div id="TextoACopiar">https://www.youtube.com/</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('BotonCopiar').addEventListener('click', copiarAlPortapapeles);
    function copiarAlPortapapeles(ev){
    var codigoACopiar = document.getElementById('TextoACopiar');
    var seleccion = document.createRange();
    seleccion.selectNodeContents(codigoACopiar);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(seleccion);
    var res = document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeRange(seleccion);
    try {
        var res = document.execCommand('copy');
        if (res)
            exito();
        else
            fracaso();

        mostrarAlerta();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        excepcion();
    }
    window.getSelection().removeRange(seleccion);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando un elemento está oculto (visibility o display) no se puede seleccionar el contenido, pero uedes lograrlo fácilmente, creando un *input* solo para asignar valor y copiar. Después lo eliminas.

```js
document.getElementById('BotonCopiar').addEventListener('click', copiarAlPortapapeles);
function copiarAlPortapapeles(ev) {
    // Obtener contenido del div oculto
    let contenido = document.getElementById('TextoACopiar').textContent;
    // Crear input
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    // Asignar contenido
    input.value = contenido;
    // Agregar input a documento
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    // Seleccionar contenido
    input.select();
    // Copiar
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // Eliminar input
    input.remove();
}
```

```css
#TextoACopiar { display:none; }
```

```html
<button id="BotonCopiar" class="btn btn-primary">Copiar URL</button>
<div id="TextoACopiar">https://www.youtube.com/</div>
```

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias, si ha funcionado no pensé que iba a ser tan sencillo como eso :0

Answer (score 3):

Como lo dice Triby, no puedes hacerlo así porque está oculto.

Hay dos formas de interactuar con el portapapeles:

`document.execCommand`: Es el que estás usando, pero como copia lo que está seleccionado y tu no quieres que esté visible el control, no te va a funcionar.

La otra forma y la que sí sirve para lo que quieres es por medio del `navigator.clipboard`, este método funciona para lo que quieres porque tú le pasas el texto como parámetro, no tienes que seleccionar nada.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var codigoACopiar = document.getElementById('TextoACopiar');
navigator.clipboard.writeText(codigoACopiar.innerHTML)
```

Es una solución más sencilla y no tienes que crear y destruir un control.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía tampoco ese método. Creí que la solución iba a ser mas compleja, pero veo que no 

Comment: Cada día se aprende algo nuevo. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo lo pude lograr realizando lo siguiente:

```
         <label>TM10</label>
         <input style="text-align: center;" id="tm10ts" type="text"  
         value="localhost/Orden.php?p=1&t=1" size="30">
         <button type="button"  onclick="Copiar('tm10ts')">Copiar</button> 


 <script>
    // Permite seleccionar y copiar el valor que contiene los input
    function Copiar(url) {
        var aux = $('#'+url);
            // alert(aux);
            aux.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
        }
</script>
```

para que esto funcione tienes que utilizar el script de jquery el cual es este:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js